# Pyserial changes values when receiving data from arduino

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a python program that I am using to obtain data from an arduino. The problem with it is that the values become different from those transmitted by the arduino. For example the maximum value my arduino should send through serial is 100 but I am receiving as much as 140+ when I use pySerial. Could someone guide me on how well to decode the outputs. I will very much appreciate that. Regards

**Arduino code**

```
void loop(){
    //values range from 1-100
    int value = 20;//any number between 1-100. 20 is just an example
    Serial.println(value);
    delay(2000);

}
```

**Python code**

```
import serial
se = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
while 1:
    line = se.readline()
    value[0] = str(int(line,16))
    print(value[0])
```

Comment: With `int(line,16)` you are getting hexadecimal values

Comment: Whats the best workaround?

Comment: `int(line)` return integer in base 10